# Why mysql's lock for update does nothing?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

- games:

  - id INT AI primary;
- bets:

  - id INT AI primary;
  - game_id INT foreign on games.id;

Next, I create a single row in `games` table with `id` equal to `1`. What I'm trying to do is concurrency limiter, to limit amount of transactions that somehow relate to this specific game and it's child to exactly one using mysql's tools. So I found mysql's `lock for update` and `lock in share mode` and tried to use both of them this way:

Opened one terminal and typed:

```
USE test;
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM `games` WHERE `id` = 1 FOR UPDATE;
```

Then opened another terminal and typed the same thing, expecting it to wait until first transaction is commited/rolled back as described in docs, but instead I got actual results (a game with that id). Same thing happens when `LOCK IN SHARE MODE` is used.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What engine do your tables use? Check with `show create table games\G`.

Comment: @fancyPants InnoDB, as usual

Comment: It works for me (`CREATE TABLE games (id INT) ENGINE=InnoDB`). No idea what's going on.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Are you on windows? I know it should not depend on that, but just in case :/

Comment: That's it, local MySQL/5.5.59 on Windows 10 Pro. I works for me in both the official command-line client and HeidiSQL. Do you have replication or some other fancy feature enabled?

Comment: I don't think so, unless it's enabled by default :/ Tried with DataGrip consoles, multiple HeidiSQL instances, just using command line and got same results everywhere. Let me check again: I start a transaction in session_1 and send "for update" request in session_1. Then, I start another transaction in session_2 and send "for update" request in session_2. It should wait until first transaction is commited, am I right?

Comment: Yes, it should wait until first transaction is either committed or rollbacked (either implicitly or explicitly) or eventually time out (there's a param to control time out value) and, as I said, that's what happens in my PC. It's important to note that it only works if there're transactions in *both* sessions but you're doing that part right as far as I can tell. I'm sorry for not being more helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182897/discussion-between-alex-wells-and-alvaro-gonzalez).